# Response from ABAP webservice returns array for multiple items but returns an object for single item

Tags: php

I'm running a webservice to connect to ABAP and return it on PHP. For multiple items, it is enclosed within an array of objects. However if it is only 1, it's only an object.

Multiple items

```
+"TStockResponse": {#398
    +"item": array:3 [
      0 => {#399
        // item data here
      }
      1 => {#400
        // item data here
      }
      2 => {#401
        // item data here
      }
    ]
  }
```

vs a single item

```
+"TStockResponse": {#393
    +"item": {#387
      // item data here
    }
  }
```

Was wondering if there's an option on PHP to determine that if the item is only 1, it encloses it to an array and proceeds to do the necessary foreach() function.

```
foreach($results->TStockResponse as $resp)
    {
         if(count($resp) == 1)
         {
              // do single task
         }
         else
         {
              foreach($resp as $res)
              {
                   // do each task
              }
         } 
    }
```

This is my current PHP code and if I try to send a single item to ABAP, I get an ErrorException on count()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be as simple as

```
if ( !is_array( $results->TStockResponse->item ) ) {
  $results->TStockResponse->item = [ $results->TStockResponse->item ];
}
```

Comment: worked thanks. however for some reason I've changed the brackets to array()